# Portscanner taking forever to scan a website

Tags: python-3.x

So I tried creating a portscanner using Python and when I scanned my PC it scanned all 65535 ports in no time. But when I tried scanning "http://scanme.nmap.org/" it took forever to do.

**CODE:**

```
import socket
def scan(port):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    host = "http://scanme.nmap.org/"
    try:
        s.connect((host, port))
        return True
    except socket.timeout:
        return None
    except socket.error:
        return None
def tryPort():
    openPorts = []
    for port in range(1, 1000):
        portOpen = scan(port)
        if portOpen == True:
            openPorts.append(port)
            print("Port " + str(port) + " is open")
        else:
            print("port " + str(port) + " is closed")
    return "\nOpen Ports: " + str(openPorts)
print(tryPort())
```

Comment: Your code says it scanned 1000 ports, not all 65535.  Why don't you put some print statements into those `except`s instead of just swallowing them?  I think you'll find that whatever is going on will become readily apparent.

Comment: Still only scanning 1000 ports, it takes forever

Comment: Timeouts, most likely.

Comment: So what do I have to do to fix it?

Comment: Have a look here: https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/code-snippets-source-code/port-scanner-in-python.  It uses a different open method, and runs over all ports in about six minutes.  There's a comment at the bottom of the post that tells how to improve performance by reducing the timeout value.

Comment: Ok I sure will. Thank you